# show field from FCE only when it is not empty

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I'm currently mapping my FCE in Templavoila. The user has an input field and should enter a text. If no text is entered the element should not be shown. Therefore I have this Typoscript Code:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value.field = field_member_tel
10.wrap = T: <span class="team-member-tel-content"> | </span>
10.if.isTrue.field = field_member_tel
```

`10.value.field` is not working. My output is only the `T:`. How do I get the value from the field?

Perhaps I should mention that this element is in a container if that makes a difference.

**EDIT:**

This leads to the same result:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value = {field_member_tel}
10.insertData = 1
10.wrap = T: <span class="team-member-tel-content"> | </span>
10.if.isTrue.field = field_member_tel
```

This is working, but I don't need a typolink here:

```
10 = TEXT
10.typolink.parameter.field = field_member_email
10.typolink.title.field = field_member_name
10.wrap = E: <span class="team-member-email-content"> | </span>
10.if.isTrue.field = field_member_email
```

Comment: The first snipped is not working because its `10.field = field_member_tel` and not `10.value.field = field_member_tel`, TEXT is a special case and the stdWrap itself.

Comment: @Merec: Perhaps you want post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Merec. The solution looks like this:

```
10 = TEXT
10.field = field_member_tel
10.wrap = T: <span class="team-member-tel-content"> | </span>
10.if.isTrue.field = field_member_tel
```